# Passing jsonfile content as request to cURL

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bunch of json files that I need to use to test a docker container. From postman I extracted the code to use and it looks something like this:

```
curl --location --request POST '<adress>' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '<json_request>'
```

Where `<json_request>` is a json formatted request to the docker and `<adress>` is the adress of the docker. How can I pass the content of those json files inplace of `<json_request>`?

Comment: What is in the files? Are they very simple? Can you be sure they don't contain any `'` for example? Or at least not both `'` and `"`? Can they be multi-line? Single-line only? Do you _need_ to run this as a `curl` command in the shell or can you write a little python or perl or anything else script to pack the data correctly?

Comment: They're multiline json files. They contains double quotes bot not single quotes. I can write a python script but I'm not experienced with using the requests library

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us some representative lines of the file then.  Especially mention that you can guarantee they will not contain single quotes. Think about cases like `Name:"O'Reilly"`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure there are no single quotes in the JSON file, this is not too hard. Try:

```
curl --location --request POST '<adress>' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw "'$(cat file.json)'"
```